# C# selenium Webdriver how to get the current timeout time

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to create the equivalent of a wait for element present command with custom timeout time

```
public static void WaitForElementPresent(string Xpath, int WaitTime, int OriginalWaitTime)
{
    try
    {
        SeleniumBrowser.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTime));
        SeleniumBrowser.driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Xpath));
        SeleniumBrowser.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(OriginalWaitTime));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find the" + Xpath + "Xpath after" + DefaultWaitTime + "second");
    }
}
```

So far my code looks like this however instead of setting a hard coded integer at the end id rather get the previous timeout time registered as an integer mid test from some obscure function and call it so to reset the timeout to its previous time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid those Implicit time outs as much as possible and stick to explicit waiting. Explicit waiting is not Thread.Sleep(time) but explicitly waiting for your element.

A huge lesson came in realizing how Implicit and Explicit waiting work. One thing to note is that C# will look for the Element immediately and when it is not found will crash with a "No Such Element" exception. If you mix implicit and explicit waiting together you will be stuck waiting until the Implicit wait time completes even if the element has been found.  Not good and caused huge time issues for tests.

I would not recommend using XPath unless needed, however, you should use one of the following ways to wait. This is mostly handled with Selenium code already.

I personally extended Selenium to do the following call with set Page Objects

Expected Condition way:

```
public static void WaitForElement(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver 
 driver, int waitTime)
        {            
            try{                
                 var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));
                 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
                 Logging.Information(elementText + " is clickable");
               }
               catch (NoSuchElementException)
               {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find the" + Xpath + "Xpath after" + DefaultWaitTime + "second");
               }
            }
        }
```

This would look like this with a mapped page object:

```
SaveButton.WaitForElement(driver);
```

I also extended selenium to use the same waiting for unmapped Page Objects.
You could do something similar with Extending the Driver class as well to match what you are currently doing.

```
public static void WaitForLocator(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int waitTime)
    {
        Logging.Action("Using locator: " + by + " to find element");
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by)); //There are several Expected conditions
        Logging.Information("Found element with locator: " + by);
    }
```

This would look like this with your current example

```
driver.WaitForLocator(By.XPath('your XPath');
```

This method will also allow you to use CSS selectors, Ids, etc by changing your By type.

The other way to explicitly wait for elements is using

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var saveButton = wait.Until(x => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Xpath));
```

Not sure you if meant to use driver.FindElements or driver.FindElement since the name of the method is WaitForElementPresent but you used driver.FindElements. Find elements returns a list of elements not just the element you were looking for.

Hope this helps.